# Errors with pip3 and apt after upgrading python and Anaconda (Debian 9)

Tags: debian, python, apt, anaconda, pip

In order to install PyMC3, I installed Python 3.8 from the official repository without realize that I already had Anaconda2 (with python 3.6). Python 3.8 worked fine but I wasn't able to make it default (even trying with updates-alternatives and PATH) and I had a problem with pip3

```
eric@debian:~$ sudo pip3 pymc3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'pip' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/__init__.py)
```

I tried every way I found to fix pip3 (purge, forced uninstall, reinstall, etc) but I always got an error. So I decided to remove Anaconda2 (that by the way it was broken since it was not possible to use `conda` command) and install Anaconda3.It works ok but now I have another issue with pip3:

```
eric@debian:~$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
eric@debian:~$ which python3
/home/eric/anaconda3/bin/python3
eric@debian:~$ pip3 --version
bash: /usr/bin/pip3: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

And when I try to remove it with `sudo apt remove python3-pip` (in order to reinstall it):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python3-crypto python3-keyring python3-keyrings.alt python3-secretstorage
  python3-wheel python3-xdg
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python3-pip
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 101 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 599 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/apt-listchanges: not found
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10
```

I tried apt autoremove and it has thrown the same apt-listchange error. 
After reading related posts, I tried:

```
eric@debian:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure apt-listchanges
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: apt-listchanges is broken or not fully installed

eric@debian:~$ sudo dpkg --purge apt-listchanges
(Reading database ... 305288 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apt-listchanges (3.10) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-listchanges.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-listchanges.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package apt-listchanges (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Deferring configuration of apt-listchanges until python3 is available
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-listchanges.postinst: 186: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-listchanges.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt-listchanges
```

According the related posts I've read, in most of the cases the problem is solved reinstalling the broken apt-listchanges, but I can't do it. Let me know if you need more info.
Thank you!